# Como pegar o atributo src de uma lista de imagens e criar um array utilizando apenas javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5, slideshow

O objetivo é um slider-show, porem quero criar um array dinâmico apenas listando algumas imagens dentro de uma div  utilizando javascript puro, por exemplo:

```
<div class= "slider">
    <img src="caminho-da-imagem-1"/>
    <img src="caminho-da-imagem-2"/>
    <img src="caminho-da-imagem-3"/>
</div>
```

Entretanto não sei como percorrer as imagens desta div, pegar e salvar o valor do atributo src em um array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você pode utilizar um `querySelectorAll` para selecionar todas as imagens, então um `map` para montar o `array`.

```js
//selecionar todos os elementos <img />  dentro de uma <div /> com à classe ".slider"
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("div.slider > img");

//realizando um mapeamento dos elementos <img />, criando um array com os valores da propriedade "src" destes elementos.
var imgs = [].map.call(elements, function (element, indice) {
  return element.src;
});

console.log(imgs);
```

```html
<div class="slider">
    <img src="caminho-da-imagem-1"/>
    <img src="caminho-da-imagem-2"/>
    <img src="caminho-da-imagem-2"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando somente javscript puro, dá pra pegar todo as imagens com querySelectorAll

e depois varrendo o array e passando o src para outro vetor

```js
//pegando todas as imagens dentro da div com classe .slider
var slider = document.querySelectorAll(".slider img");

var imagens_slider = [];

//varrendo array e pegando imagens do src para um novo array
for(cont=0; cont < slider.length; cont++){
   
  imagens_slider.push(slider[cont].src);
  
}

console.log(imagens_slider)
```

```html
<div class= "slider">
    <img src="caminho-da-imagem-1"/>
    <img src="caminho-da-imagem-2"/>
    <img src="caminho-da-imagem-2"/>
</div>
```